# Non-repeating random numbers in vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, random, numbers

I'm trying to store random numbers in vector, but I want each number to be unique. Can I do that with for loop without using unique() or random_shuffle() ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    vector<int> v;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

          v.push_back(rand() % 30);
    }

    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {

        cout << v[j] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to randomize the order?

Comment: Why are you insisting on a difficult and inefficient solution? Generate an ordered vector, and shuffle it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of... https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+unique+random+number

Comment: And if you don't want to use the standard library's random shuffle, write your own. The [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is fairly easy to implement with rand() itself.

Comment: There are no just "random numbers", you have to specify the distribution. If you don't care what about the distribution, use 1,2,3,...,30.

Comment: For a wonderful example of how to do this, [see the documentation for `std::iota`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota). One caveat: this requires a working `std::random_device`, something mingw does not have.

Comment: You did not specify whether you have to use values in `[0, 30)` range. Do you?

Comment: Do you want it in a vector, or do you want generate_next() in O(1)? The latter is more tricky, you might get there by enumerating all permutations (not in code, mathematically) and generate a random in that range. Now, that random can be generated bit-by-bit...

Answer (score 4):

The classic [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) can also be used to generate a shuffled vector directly, in one pass

```
vector<unsigned> v;

for (unsigned i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
{
  unsigned j = rand() % (i + 1);
  if (j < i)
  {
    v.push_back(v[j]);
    v[j] = i;
  }
  else
    v.push_back(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably generate vector and just shuffle it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <utility>

int main()
{

    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(NULL)));
    size_t const n = 30;
    std::vector<int> v(n);

    //make vector
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        v[i] = static_cast<int>(i);

    //shuffle
    for (size_t i = n - 1; i > 0; --i)
        std::swap(v[i], v[static_cast<size_t>(rand()) % (i + 1)]);

    //print
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
        std::cout << (i > 0 ? "," : "") << v[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Prints, for example:

```
27,24,2,23,13,6,9,14,11,5,15,18,16,29,22,12,26,20,10,8,28,25,7,4,1,17,0,3,19,21
```

Comment: Your homemade ad-hoc shuffle produces non-uniform distribution (which is normally implied/required in such problems). Better use `std::shuffle` or at least implement Fisher-Yates shuffle (aka "Knuth shuffle"), which is an extremely simple algorithm.

Comment: It appears that you meant to implement a "forward" Fisher-Yates shuffle from the Wikipedia page. But for that it is important to keep in mind that the random index for the swap should be generated in `[i, n)` range. You generate an index in `[0, n)` range. This is not Fisher-Yates and this is still non-uniform.